# SQL Server : FOR XML specific output

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have been trying (with no success yet) to produce the following XML output

```
<table>
    <row>
        <column name="column_name">[value]</column>
        <column name="column_name">[value]</column>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column name="column_name">[value]</column>
        <column name="column_name">[value]</column>
    </row>
</table>
```

Can anyone suggest a route that will allow me to achieve this output?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Just google "SQL SERVER SELECT FOR XML".  There's tons of stuff on this including tutorials and many answers on this site.  If you have a specific question, please let us know.

Comment: Could you give some examples of SQL statements you've tried so far?  StackOverflow is best when you have a specific question or issue that you are trying to resolve based on the effort you've put in so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is still of interest, but the code was this:

(The trick is the "empty node" between the two column declarations...)

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(col1 INT, col2 VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,'test1'),(2,'test2');

SELECT 'col1' AS [column/@name]
      ,col1 AS [column]

      ,'' --this is needed to allow the same name twice...

      ,'col2' AS [column/@name]
      ,col2 AS [column]
FROM @tbl
FOR XML PATH('row'),ROOT('table');

/*
<table>
  <row>
    <column name="col1">1</column>
    <column name="col2">test1</column>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column name="col1">2</column>
    <column name="col2">test2</column>
  </row>
</table>
*/
```